# NGINX inbound proxy/redirect

Tags: nginx, nginx-config

Sorry if this question comes across slightly vague, but I have never had to use NGINX for something like this. What I am basically looking for is an inbound nginx server that will then route the requests to my internal applications. Main idea is due to vpn routing I do not control. The vpn would be routing any traffic to my internal nginx server and from there I need it to reach out to other applications.

So basically I'm having trouble with this:

```
http app1.int > nginx (ex 10.10.10.1) server > http://application1.int (on internal AWS IP)
http app2.int > nginx (ex 10.10.10.1) server > http://application2.int (on internal AWS IP)
```

and so on and so forth.

Best I can get right now is each a seperate conf file containing something like this:

```
    server_name app1.int;

    location / {
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_pass http://application1.int:80;
    }
}
```

Only problem I am having is in a browser it is still showing app1.int and not the URL for the tool itself. I have tried proxy redirects (which I think should work, but its just not).

Any idea what I should do or be looking at to get this done?

Comment: Sorry, but I can't get that together. You want to "http app1.int", and you config nginx to react to app1.int, but then you don't want to "http app1.int"? -- If only "app1.int" is reachable from vpn, but "application1.int" is not, your config is correct. You reach application1.int though the nginx tunnel while accessing app1.int...